# Error while attempting filling a Date table on APEX with PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to fill a date table on APEX with dates from '2017-01-01' to '2025-12-31'.
I already created the table and columns using :

```
CREATE TABLE CALENDAR_TBL (
    "DATE_ROWID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "DATE" DATE,
    "DAY_NUMBER" NUMBER,
    "MONTH_NUMBER" NUMBER,
    "MONTH_NAME" VARCHAR2(20),
    "YEAR" NUMBER,
    "YEAR_MONTH_NUMBER" NUMBER,
    "YEAR_MONTH_NAME" VARCHAR2(20),
    "DAY_NAME" VARCHAR2(20),
    CONSTRAINT "DATE_ROWID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DATE_ROWID")
 USING INDEX ENABLE
)
/
```

I created a trigger and a sequence to fill the `DATE_ROWID` column each time a line is added.

I made this script to fill the table :

```
DECLARE
  start_date DATE := TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
  end_date DATE := TO_DATE('2050-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD');
  current_date DATE := start_date;
BEGIN
  WHILE current_date <= end_date LOOP
    INSERT INTO CALENDAR_TBL (DATE, DAY_NUMBER, MONTH_NUMBER, MONTH_NAME, YEAR, YEAR_MONTH_NUMBER, YEAR_MONTH_NAME, DAY_NAME)
    VALUES (
      current_date,
      TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date, 'DD')),
      TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date, 'MM')),
      TO_CHAR(current_date, 'MONTH'),
      TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date, 'YYYY')),
      TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date, 'YYYYMM')),
      TO_CHAR(current_date, 'YYYY MONTH'),
      TO_CHAR(current_date, 'DAY')
    );
    current_date := current_date + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

But as I run it, I get the error :

```
ORA-06550: line 7, column 39:
PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 673
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 659
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1829


5. BEGIN
6.   WHILE current_date <= end_date LOOP
7.     INSERT INTO CALENDAR_TBL (DATE, DAY_NUMBER, MONTH_NUMBER, MONTH_NAME, YEAR, YEAR_MONTH_NUMBER, YEAR_MONTH_NAME, DAY_NAME)
8.     VALUES (
9.       current_date,
```

And I don't really understand where my procedure goes wrong ...

Thank's a lot for helping.

Comment: Use double quotes for column `DATE` in your insert statement. `INSERT INTO CALENDAR_TBL ("DATE",`..........`and so on...`

Comment: Please let me know, if you still face more issues

Comment: DATE and YEAR are actually keywords. Thus, better use "DATE" and "YEAR". And why not use a single insert select?

Comment: `DATE` and `YEAR` are both **reserved words**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words. (SQL also have _non-reserved words_.)

Comment: @jarlh `DATE` is an [Oracle reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621), `YEAR` is not.

Comment: @Tushar It actually worked thank you very much for your help. But as I switched solution not to involve trigger in my creation table, I used another way to fill my table

Comment: @MT0, oops, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use virtual columns in the `CALENDAR_TBL` so that you never get into the situation where the `DATE` and the other columns are out-of-sync (and an `IDENTITY` column for the primary key):

```sql
CREATE TABLE CALENDAR_TBL (
    DATE_ROWID NUMBER
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "DATE"     DATE
               NOT NULL
               UNIQUE,
    DAY        NUMBER(2,0)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(DAY FROM "DATE")),
    MONTH      NUMBER(2,0)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "DATE")),
    MONTH_NAME VARCHAR2(9)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(TO_CHAR("DATE", 'fmMONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') AS VARCHAR2(9))),
    YEAR       NUMBER(4,0)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "DATE")),
    YEAR_MONTH_NUMBER NUMBER(6,0)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR("DATE", 'YYYYMM'))),
    YEAR_MONTH_NAME VARCHAR2(14)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(TO_CHAR("DATE", 'fmYYYY MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') AS VARCHAR2(14))),
    DAY_NAME   VARCHAR2(9)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(TO_CHAR("DATE", 'fmDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') AS VARCHAR2(9))),
    CONSTRAINT "DATE_ROWID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DATE_ROWID") USING INDEX ENABLE
);
```

*Note: `DATE` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621) and you would need to use a quoted identifier to use it. It would be better to use a different identifier.*

Then you can use the insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO calendar_tbl ("DATE")
SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' + LEVEL - 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2017-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2050-12-31';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K4V6z_Ps)

Comment: Not sure if it wouldn't be better to have a view on top of a table containing just the date column. Moreover, generally, in a calendar table there should be some info as to whether a certain day is a holiday, for that is really important info for the ERP system.

Comment: @BogdanDincescu Holidays are outside the scope of the OP's question (there are lots of things that "could" be included but are irrelevant to answering the OP's question).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a single insert select, like below:

```
 INSERT INTO CALENDAR_TBL ("DATE", DAY_NUMBER, MONTH_NUMBER, MONTH_NAME, "YEAR", YEAR_MONTH_NUMBER, YEAR_MONTH_NAME, DAY_NAME)
    with td as (
    select TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')+level current_date
    from dual
    connect by level<=TO_DATE('2050-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')-TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
    )
    select
          current_date,
          TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date, 'DD')),
          TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date, 'MM')),
          TO_CHAR(current_date, 'MONTH'),
          TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date, 'YYYY')),
          TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(current_date, 'YYYYMM')),
          TO_CHAR(current_date, 'YYYY MONTH'),
          TO_CHAR(current_date, 'DAY')
    from tb;
```

Comment: `YEAR` is not a reserved word in Oracle.

Comment: Also, you need to subtract 1 in the hierarchical query otherwise you will miss the first day.